# Scan QR Code and open URL – Swift AVFoundation library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, swift3

Sorry, this is my very first iOS app! I am trying to implement a very simple QR code scanner to the app using QRCodeReader.swift but I have no idea how to handle the URL from the result. It is supposed to redirect instantly to the link but is not working. Thank you!

```
func reader(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController, didScanResult result: QRCodeReaderResult) {
reader.stopScanning()


dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in


let url = URL(string: result.value)!
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}


}
}
```

Comment: Did you find this problem when you open the system settings?

Comment: Not yet! It scans the QR code but doesn't go to the link.

Comment: So what is this link? Because I use your code and it works.

Comment: It is supposed to open the default browser with any url

Comment: Try this https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15682381/27668334-1ca69ebe-5cb3-11e7-88a4-7793cd41272f.png

Comment: Thanks, It's working! Is it possible to check whether it is a valid url first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

***`Optional Chaining`***:
 Optional Chaining as an Alternative to Forced Unwrapping.

You can check scanned `String` is `url`,`xml`,`JSON` by `optional chaining`. For more go to apple document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

```
if let url = URL(string: result.value){ //check whether the string is URL
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}else {
    //do more if scanned text is not url string
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to check if the string is URL first? Thank you!